# Use varchar with many characters or clob for 500 characters text?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have text strings that may be up to `500` characters.

Is it better to store them as `varchar(500)` or as `clob`?
Please also give a reason for your opinion.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `clob` in Postgres - the equivalent is `text`.

[There is no difference in performance or storage requirement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) between `varchar(500)` or `text`.

The only difference is documentation and what you can store. `varchar(500)` clearly states that you never want to store more than 500 characters. You can see this more like a check constraint (business rule) than a technical configuration.

`text` (without a check cosntraint) on the other hand says that you have no (business) restrictions on the length of the data in that column.